# Where can I download the ReportDefinition.xsd for SSRS 2008 R2

Tags: reporting-services, rdlc, dynamic-rdlc-generation

I need to dynamic generation rdlc file,but MS website link is broken:
[reportdefinition 2010](http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2010/01/reportdefinition)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an instance of the SSRS service running, it should be accessible from http://~servername~/reportserver/reportdefinition.xsd

Comment: I have not install SSRS service,can you please send to me? jrt324@gmail.com

Comment: I don't have access to an SSRS instance. Try this: http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition/ReportDefinition.xsd